# Docker: Cannot create container for service my-service: No command specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to deploy my Node application to different environment and as part of the process, I have set up a GitHub Actions workflow which has 2 jobs namely, build and deploy_dev. build job will build the image and upload it as artifact and deploy_dev job will download the artifact, tag it and push it to ECR.

I did not encounter any error while building or tagging but, while running the pulled image within ECR, Im getting the below error so, I'm not sure if it's due to corrupted image or issue with the way im building or tagging.

```
Error: Recreating ce3fc36b598e_my-service ... error
for test-service  Cannot create container for service test-service: No command specified
```

Here is my workflow file:

```yaml
name: my-service
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch: null
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Cache Docker layers
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
          key: '${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ github.sha }}'
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Build docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64
          provenance: false
          cache-from: 'type=local,src=/tmp/.buildx-cache'
          cache-to: 'type=local,dest=/tmp/.buildx-cache'
          outputs: 'type=docker,dest=/tmp/my-service.tar'
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-service
          path: /tmp/my-service.tar
  deploy_dev:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: dev
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-service
          path: /tmp
      - name: Configure aws credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: '${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}'
          aws-secret-access-key: '${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}'
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - name: Amazon ECR "Login" Action for GitHub Actions
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
        with:
          registry-type: private
          skip-logout: false
          mask-password: true
      - name: Deploy to dev
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: '${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}'
        run: >
          docker image import /tmp/my-service.tar ${{ env.ECR_REGISTRY
          }}/my-service:dev

          docker push ${{ env.ECR_REGISTRY }}/my-service:dev
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
COPY app.js /usr/src/app

ADD src /usr/src/app/src
ADD tests /usr/src/app/tests
ADD migrations /usr/src/app/migrations

COPY .eslintrc.js /usr/src/app
COPY .prettierrc.js /usr/src/app
COPY migrate-mongo-config.js /usr/src/app/migrate-mongo-config.js

COPY .env.example /usr/src/app/.env

RUN npm install
RUN npm run lint

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I'm not sure about the mistake or the way I'm consuming tar file for tagging and pushing.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/757210/no-command-specified-from-re-imported-docker-image-container.